# Solr/Lucene fieldCache OutOfMemory error sorting on dynamic field

Tags: solr, lucene, out-of-memory

We have a Solr core that has about 250 `TrieIntField`s (declared as `dynamicField`). There are about 14M docs in our Solr index and many documents have some value in many of these fields. We have a need to sort on all of these 250 fields over a period of time.

The issue we are facing is that the underlying lucene `fieldCache` gets filled up very quickly. We have a 4 GB box and the index size is 18 GB. After a sort on 40 or 45 of these dynamic fields, the memory consumption is about 90% and we start getting OutOfMemory errors.

For now, we have a cron job running every minute restarting tomcat if the total memory consumed is more than 80%.

From what I have read, I understand that restricting the number of distinct values on sortable Solr fields will bring down the `fieldCache` space. The values in these sortable fields can be any integer from 0 to 33000 and quite widely distributed. We have a few scaling solutions in mind, but what is the best way to handle this whole issue?

UPDATE: We thought instead of sorting, if we did boosting it won't go to fieldCache. So instead of issuing a query like

`select?q=name:alba&sort=relevance_11 desc`

we tried

`select?q={!boost relevance_11}name:alba`

but unfortunately boosting also populates the field cache :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have two options:

1) Add more memory.
2) Force Solr not to use the field cache by specifying `facet.method=enum`, [as per documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.method).

There's also a [solr-user mailing list thread](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Lucene-FieldCache-Out-of-memory-exception-td3950298.html) discussing the same problem.

Unless your index is huge, I'd go with option 1). RAM is cheap these days.

Comment: Isn't `facet.method` applicable only for facet queries? How to disable field cache for sort queries?

Comment: While increasing memory is one obvious solution, our servers are hosted by rackspace and a 4 GB server costs $175/mo, but a 15 GB server (which can almost hold our entire Solr index) costs $657/mo (see http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/pricing/). Before throwing more money at this problem for a cache that we don't even need, I want to find how to avoid it entirely.

Comment: I mailed the solr-users list. Erick Erickson says: "I sure don't see how this can work given the constraints. Just to hold the
values, assuming that each doc holds a value in 150 fields, you have 150 *
4 * 14,000,000 or 8.4G of memory required, and you just don't have that
much memory to play around with.

Sharding seems silly for 14M docs, but that might be what's necessary. Or
get hardware with lots of memory.

Or redefine the problem so you don't have to sort so many fields. Not quite
sure how do do that off the top of my head, but"  so we are now reworking our schema! I accept ur answer

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this is quite interesting.

Answer (score 0):

We have a way to rework the schema by keeping a single sort field. The dynamic fields we have are like `relevance_CLASSID`. The current schema has a unique key `NODEID` and a multi-valued field `CLASSID` - the relevance scores are for these class Ids. If we instead keep one document per classId per nodeId i.e. the new schema will have `NODEID:CLASSID` as unique key and store some redundant information across documents with the same `NODEID`, then we can sort on a single field `relevance` and do a filter query on CLASSID.