# Exact result in EdgeNGramFilterFactory (Solr search)

Tags: solr

I use EdgeNGramFilterFactory with config in schema  file

```
<fieldType name="prefix_token_text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="1">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="20" side="front" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>            
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I have eight field in schema. I have config

```
<field name="text" type="prefix_token_text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

And

```
<copyField source="AccountName" dest="text" />
```

Data index of me about three hundred million.

When If I search for

```
sanosuke
```

I get results like

```
sanosuke3
sanosuke2
sanosuke1
sanosuke
sanosukebn
sanosukeqns
......
```

I want result **sanosuke** on top. Why is it so? Help me. Thanks All :)

Answer (score 1):

Add [sort](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#sort) to the query. Like q=text:sanonuke&sort=text asc

Comment: hi O. Klein, i meet error HTTP Status 500 - Java heap space java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at

Comment: i have about 200 million record, server 16GB Ram, i increase memory java from 4GB to 8GB.But when i query have order is error. I query not order is normal :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393248/solr-lucene-fieldcache-outofmemory-error-sorting-on-dynamic-field

Comment: This doesn't look like a correct answer. He's asking about the most accurate match being on top, not how to sort alphabetically.