# Apache Solr - Physical memory growing too fast upon dataimport

Tags: solr

I am running the dataimport command nightly (127.0.0.1:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import)

After a few days, I look at my solr admin panel and the physical memory is over 4gb.  If I delete the index (delete all files in the data directory) and then run the dataimport, the physical memory goes down to 1.1gb.  Without deleting it, the physical memory grows at a very fast rate.

Do I need additional parameters like clean=true?  I want to run a cron task that is essentially the same as deleting the data directory, then running the full import to keep my physical memory as low as possible.

I am using the default cache settings for solr 4.0.

```
<query>

<maxBooleanClauses>1024</maxBooleanClauses>

<filterCache class="solr.FastLRUCache"
             size="512"
             initialSize="512"
             autowarmCount="0"/>


<queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                 size="512"
                 initialSize="512"
                 autowarmCount="0"/>


<documentCache class="solr.LRUCache"
               size="512"
               initialSize="512"
               autowarmCount="0"/>

<enableLazyFieldLoading>true</enableLazyFieldLoading>

<queryResultWindowSize>20</queryResultWindowSize>
<queryResultMaxDocsCached>200</queryResultMaxDocsCached>


<listener event="newSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
  <arr name="queries">
    <!--
       <lst><str name="q">solr</str><str name="sort">price asc</str></lst>
       <lst><str name="q">rocks</str><str name="sort">weight asc</str></lst>
      -->
  </arr>
</listener>
<listener event="firstSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
  <arr name="queries">
    <lst>
      <str name="q">static firstSearcher warming in solrconfig.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </arr>
</listener>

<useColdSearcher>false</useColdSearcher>

<maxWarmingSearchers>2</maxWarmingSearchers>

</query>
```

Comment: For full import `clean=true` is the default. See here: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Commands. The memory could be consumed by various aspects, not just the full import. Can you check your cache settings in your solrconfig.xml and the cache stats at 127.0.0.1:8983/solr/admin/stats.jsp?

Comment: I checked the stats.  What should I be looking for?  I'm very confused as to why there isn't a built in function that does the equivalent of deleting and re-importing the data directory.

Comment: It looks like all your "Solr-managed" caches are fine. A frequent cause of Solr consuming too much memory is due to the fieldCache (https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#The_Lucene_FieldCache), which you cannot configure. fieldCache gets populated when you sort on a field. If your application is sorting on too many fields (especially dynamic fields) this cache could consume memory. Check `entries_count` and `insanity_count` under fieldCache on the stats page.

Comment: When you say you delete the index and then run the data import, do you also restart jetty (or whatever container you are using) before running the import command? Restarting the container will delete all the caches, including the fieldCache, which may explain why Solr starts with less memory. But once the caches get populated, more memory will be consumed.

Comment: Yes, I restart Jetty.  That must be it.  Is there a way to delete the caches from cron?

Comment: I don't think you can just delete the caches without restarting jetty. The fieldCache keeps one entry per sort field. If you run many queries sorting on different fields (especially dynamic fields), it will get populated and you start getting out of memory exceptions. Your best bet is to rework your schema. You can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393248/solr-lucene-fieldcache-outofmemory-error-sorting-on-dynamic-field