# Sorting by a hash value with Solr / Sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, solr, sunspot

I have a RoR application that uses Sunspot to access Solr. All the latest versions.

My indexed documents have a hash where the keys are the user_id and the value is the time the user first saw the document.

How can I sort the results of a search by the user's date values? I want this to be done in Solr rather than in RoR due to the amount of data involved - pulling in all the results just to do the sort in RoR is not going to be pretty.

Is this possible natively in Solr? If so, can Sunspot also handle it?

Answer (score 0):

In Solr REST API, to sort by the time field, you simply need to add a `sort` query param. For example, if you want to sort user_id's 1, 2, and 3 by when they accessed the document, you can issue a query like 
`http://localhost:8983/solr/CORE/select?q=user_id:(1 OR 2 OR 3)&sort=timefield desc` 
to solr.

I don't know sunspot or ruby, but looking at the search example at http://sunspot.github.com/ I guess you could do sth. like this?

```
Post.search do
  user_id '1 OR 2 OR 3'
  order_by :timefield, :desc
end
```

Comment: The issue is that each user has their own access time, and I need to sort by that value for the specific user in question. I don't see how this solution handles my requirement.

Comment: I didn't know that you could actually store a hash as a field inside a solr document. I thought you could only store simple types like int, float, string, text and multi-valued fields? I misunderstood your qn. I am curious, so can you tell how you are storing a hash in the document?

Comment: I think you're right. Any idea how I could have a different sort per user based on a per-user property in each document?

Comment: You can use dynamic fields (https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Dynamic_fields). You can have a dynamic field like `accesstime_*` and store `accesstime_USERID` in each document and then sort on that. But beware sorting on dynamic fields will quickly populate the unconfigurable fieldCache and you will start getting out of memory exceptions soon (See the trouble I ran into here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393248/solr-lucene-fieldcache-outofmemory-error-sorting-on-dynamic-field/13401665).