# OutOfMemoryError with Solr -> huge 1Gb FieldCacheImpl$StringIndexCache

Tags: java, solr, out-of-memory

On Solr 1.4, do you know what could cause an OutOfMemoryError on this class?

```
org.apache.lucene.search.FieldCacheImpl$StringIndexCache#1
```

It takes one gb of ram, and the underlying WeakHashMap only has 700 keys.

---

The cache configuration:

```
<filterCache
  class="solr.FastLRUCache"
  size="1024"
  initialSize="0"
  autowarmCount="0"/>

<queryResultCache
  class="solr.FastLRUCache"
  size="1024"
  initialSize="0"
  autowarmCount="0"/>


<documentCache
  class="solr.FastLRUCache"
  size="1024"
  initialSize="0"
  autowarmCount="0"/>
```

Normally my objects are quite large but not so much, not as much as more than 1mb per object!

The Xmx is 2GB.

3 million documents are indexed.

The OOM appears at query time.

Comment: Usually the case is observed with using fields for sorting and faceting with large number of terms in it ? also how are you querying solr ? solrj ?

Comment: I noticed a query sorting by Date and then DocumentId (distinct values). It seems the FieldCache contains some DocumentId related entries.

Comment: I use Lucene 2.9 and it seems the heap usage has been reduced with Lucene 4: http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2010/07/lucenes-ram-usage-for-searching.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check your /admin/stats.jsp for the Solr core, you can see this under FieldCache:

`Provides introspection of the Lucene FieldCache, this is **NOT** a cache that is managed by Solr.`

You can do nothing about this cache in Solr, other than changing your queries. Most likely you are sorting on dynamic fields or doing faceting without using `facet.method=enum`. See [Solr/Lucene fieldCache OutOfMemory error sorting on dynamic field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393248/solr-lucene-fieldcache-outofmemory-error-sorting-on-dynamic-field)