# Problems with stats.field query with solr

Tags: solr, statistics, faceted-search, solrcloud

My tomcat configured with 30G memory，When I use `stats.field` query with solrcloud, it reported **memory overflow error**. Is there need to configure those parameters? My query is

```
select?q=*:*&indent=true&wt=json&stats=true&stats.field=privce&stats.facet=Commodity&rows=0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solr/Lucene fieldCache OutOfMemory error sorting on dynamic field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393248/solr-lucene-fieldcache-outofmemory-error-sorting-on-dynamic-field)